# React + Typescript - Reaproveitar função de um componente em outro dando erro

Tags: typescript, react

Dentro de uma tela de cadastro tenho um pop-up para cadastrar um registro filho da tabela em questão.

Tenho uma função que faz com que o pop-up apareça e desapareça no botão "Cancelar".
Decidi montar um componente separado para esse filho e em pesquisas encontrei uma forma de montar o esquema mas ele parece não funcionar.

O pop-up (que está sendo renderizado na classe filho) aparece.
Mas o problema está na função que não é executada no botão de "Cancelar".

Aqui tenho como está a classe filho

```
interface IProps{
        action: () => void
 }

 export default class TelaCadastroAditivo extends React.Component<IProps,{}> 
 {
     render() {
     return (
        <div>
              <div className="col-md-3"> <button  onClick={() => 
                 this.props.action}>Cancelar</button></div>
          </div>
      );
   }
}
```

E aqui a classe pai

```
import TelaCadastroAditivo from '../DAO/TelaCadastroAditivo';

class AddFeed extends React.Component<ISpaFeedWebpartProps, {}>{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }
    public telaAditivo = () => {
        alert("Teste");
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <TelaCadastroAditivo  action={this.telaAditivo}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não está invocando a função, deveria ser `onClick={() => this.props.action()}` ou `onClick={this.props.action}`. Com `onClick={() => this.props.action}` você está apenas retornando uma referência a função sem invoca-la.

Comment: @user140828 Era isso mesmo.
Muito obrigada.